# Use AWS EC2 to run Selenium to launch Chrome browser while demote desktop is not logged on

Tags: selenium, amazon-ec2

I have AWS EC2 Windows instance where I have scheduled tasks to run a .bat file
The bat file invokes Python script to launch Chrome via Selenium to open website in headless mode.

The problem is the headless mode does not work on some webpages as expected, the webpage works perfectly fine in normal mode but in headless mode, it simply goes blank.

Therefore, I have to remove --headless option, and then the problem is in that case I have to literally log into my EC2 instance and watch the script run, otherwise, the browser won't open.

Therefore, my question is:

How to make AWS EC2 run my script just like I log on to the machine when I was offline?

Comment: Can you please provide the *.bat file to show how Selenium is being triggered on your AWS EC2 Windows instance?

Comment: @PdC The .bat file is just a single command line: python python/open_webpage.py